# JAVA Doubly Linked List - count equal data items

Tags: java, list, count, doubly-linked-list

I am still a little confused on how to implement a doubly linked list. After researching and finding some information about them, I've got a good visual of how some of the basic functions work, such as add, remove etc. However, If I wanted to write a method for a DLList called countEquals (E check) that walks the entire list and counts the number of items in the list that are equal to the "Check" data item passed to the method, how would I write this. The instructions say I cannot use a for-each loop or an iterator, but a loop of some sort must be used. After the list is fully traversed, return the number of items that are equal to "check". Here is some code that I have tried to write for this:

internal references of DLList: Fields (next, data, prev) Members (size), head and tail.

```
 public int countEquals(E Check){
      currentNode = head; 
      int count = 0;
      while (currentNode != null) {
            if (currentNode.data == check) {
                count ++;
            else {
                currentNode.next = currentNode;
            }
      return count;
  }
```

I'm not too sure if this will correctly walk a doubly linked list, if I have to write more pointer assignments? I was thinking that because I'm not adding any nodes, but just walking a list, I wouldnt need to do the pointers.

Comment: Your code looks almost correct. No matter what, you want the `currentNode.next = currentNode;` to execute so move it out of the else. You probably want to do `.equals()` instead of `==` for comparison as well.

Comment: 1. missing a closing bracket. 2. what @vandale said.

Comment: Oh okay I see what you guys mean. Because in the code that I have written, if it runs into a node that is Null, it will automatically return the count, instead of continue to traverse the list. Thank you for all the help guys. In this situation how would I implement a .equals() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there, good effort. However, just a couple of things. First, you may want to look into using `something.equals()` rather than `==` since the latter is for object identity rather than value equality.

Second. the logic for traversing the list is slightly off. It needs to be done *regardless* of whether an item was found, and the *sides* of the assignment should be reversed.

Have a look at the following pseudo-code for guidance:

```
def countEquals(check):
    currentNode = head
    count = 0
    while currentNode != null:
        if currentNode.data == check:
            count = count + 1
        currentNode = currentNode.next
    return count;
```

Comment: I have a question about the assignments part of the code. What is the difference between the two assignment statements? currentNode.next = currentNode. Would this basically point back to itself??

Comment: @Amateur_Haskell, yes, that's right. It actually sets the next pointer of the _current node_ to point to itself, effectively truncating the list at that point. The correct way, sets the local pointer to point to the next node.

Answer (score 1):

do it this way, if data is integer

```
 while (currentNode != null) {
            if (currentNode.data == check) {
                count ++;
                currentNode.next = currentNode;

            }
            else {
                currentNode.next = currentNode;
            }
  }
  return count;
```